# How to create a macro which will copy data from row to column, using conditions?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2016

I am using currently v lookup to find and place values against the specific item. however, I am looking for help for a VB macro which will out the data in defined outcome.

please see 1st screen shot of raw data
[image]

second screen shot, should be the outcome.
[image]

Please note the "site" is not constant it can be any value, so I have put all site in column A .

currently V look is doing the job well. but makes the file  crash sometime.

Comment: Tip: You just need to add a helper column in your first screenshot, that combines `Date` and `Site` so you can lookup both criteria at once. See [VLOOKUP with multiple critiera](https://exceljet.net/formula/vlookup-with-multiple-critiera) for a detailed example.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this with a Pivot Table using your original data source with NO changes in the table layout.

Drag the columns as shown below *(you'll want to rename them from the default names)*: For `Columns`, drag the `Date` field there first.  The `Σ Values` field will appear after you've dragged two Fields to the Values area, and should be below `Date`.

[image]

And with some formatting changes from the default, the result can look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your source data?
If you change your data to look like the table "Changed Source Data" below you can solve your issue with a pivot table.

**Solution with a Pivot Table**

[image: use pivot 2]

**Changed Source Data**

[image: use pivot 1]

Answer (score 0):

There question can easily solved with pivot table. For practice i have create the below.

Let us assume that:

1. Data appears in Sheet "Data"
2. Results will be populated in sheet "Results"

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Sub Allocation()

   Dim LastRow As Long, Row As Long, Column As Long, Invetory As Long, Sold As Long, Remaining As Long, LastRowRes As Long, LastColRes As Long, CurrentCol As Long, CurrentRow As Long, i As Long, y As Long
   Dim iDate As Date
   Dim Site As String
   Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsResults As Worksheet
   Dim ExcistSite As Boolean, ExcistDate As Boolean

   Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
   Set wsResults = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results")

   LastRow = wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

   wsResults.UsedRange.Clear

   For Row = 2 To LastRow

       iDate = wsData.Cells(Row, 1).Value
       Site = wsData.Cells(Row, 2).Value
       Invetory = wsData.Cells(Row, 3).Value
       Sold = wsData.Cells(Row, 4).Value
       Remaining = wsData.Cells(Row, 5).Value

       If Row = 2 Then

           With wsResults.Range("B1:D1")
               .Merge
               .Value = iDate
           End With

           wsResults.Range("A2").Value = "Site"
           wsResults.Range("A2").Offset(1, 0).Value = Site
           wsResults.Range("B2").Value = "Invetory"
           wsResults.Range("B2").Offset(1, 0).Value = Invetory
           wsResults.Range("C2").Value = "Sold"
           wsResults.Range("C2").Offset(1, 0).Value = Sold
           wsResults.Range("D2").Value = "Remaining"
           wsResults.Range("D2").Offset(1, 0).Value = Remaining

       Else
           'Check if Site appears
           LastRowRes = wsResults.Cells(wsResults.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

           For i = 3 To LastRowRes
               ExcistSite = False
               If wsResults.Cells(i, 1).Value = Site Then
                   CurrentRow = i
                   ExcistSite = True
                   Exit For
               Else
                   CurrentRow = i + 1
               End If
           Next i

           If ExcistSite = False Then
               wsResults.Cells(CurrentRow, 1).Value = Site
           End If

           'Check if date appears
           LastColRes = wsResults.Cells(1, wsResults.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

           For y = 2 To LastColRes
               ExcistDate = False
               If wsResults.Cells(1, y).Value = iDate Then
                   CurrentCol = y
                   ExcistDate = True
                   Exit For
               Else
                   CurrentCol = y + 1
               End If
           Next y

           If ExcistDate = False Then

               wsResults.Cells(2, CurrentCol + 2).Value = "Invetory"
               wsResults.Cells(i, CurrentCol + 2).Value = Invetory
               wsResults.Cells(2, CurrentCol + 3).Value = "Sold"
               wsResults.Cells(i, CurrentCol + 3).Value = Sold
               wsResults.Cells(2, CurrentCol + 4).Value = "Remaining"
               wsResults.Cells(i, CurrentCol + 4).Value = Remaining

               With wsResults.Range(Cells(1, LastColRes + 3), Cells(1, LastColRes + 5))
                   .Merge
                   .Value = iDate
               End With

           Else
               wsResults.Cells(CurrentRow, CurrentCol).Value = Invetory
               wsResults.Cells(CurrentRow, CurrentCol + 1).Value = Sold
               wsResults.Cells(CurrentRow, CurrentCol + 2).Value = Remaining
           End If

       End If

   Next Row

   LastColRes = wsResults.Cells(1, wsResults.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   LastRowRes = wsResults.Cells(wsResults.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

   With wsResults.Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(1, LastColRes))
       With .Font
           .Bold = True
           .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
       End With
       With .Interior
           .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
       End With
   End With

   With wsResults.Cells(2, 1)
       With .Font
           .Bold = True
           .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
       End With
       With .Interior
           .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
       End With
   End With

   For i = 2 To LastColRes Step 3

       With wsResults.Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(LastRowRes, i))

           With .Interior
               .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
               .TintAndShade = 0.399975585192419
           End With

       End With

   Next i

   For i = 3 To LastColRes + 3 Step 3

       With wsResults.Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(LastRowRes, i + 1))

           With .Font
               .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark2
               .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
           End With

       End With

   Next i

   With wsResults.UsedRange
       .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
       .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
       .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
       .EntireColumn.AutoFit
   End With

   End Sub
   ```